# Multiple pushpins are not being displayed on Windows phone 7 map

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am trying to populate a map control using the map layer however whenever I try to add all the pushpins to the map only one is displayed. I checked to see if the values were being added to the map layer and they exist so what is the problem.

```
    private readonly CredentialsProvider _credentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider(App.Id);
    private static readonly GeoCoordinate DefaultLocation = new GeoCoordinate(18.091020, -77.377636);
    public List<Pushpin> Pushpins = new List<Pushpin>();

    public map()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    var layer = new MapLayer();
        var api = new PPSApi.PPSApi();

        api.GetAllPotholes((res) =>
        {
            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                foreach (var pothole in res.Data.pothole)
                {
                    Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
                    pin.Location.Latitude = pothole.Latitude;
                    pin.Location.Longitude = pothole.Longitude;
                    layer.AddChild(pin,pin.Location);
                    Debug.WriteLine(pin.Location);

                }
            }

        });
        PotholeMap.Children.Add(layer);
```

[Screenshot of map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVif1.png)

Comment: Maybe you should try to move the line: 
PotholeMap.Children.Add(layer);

Before the call to your API. It might have a weird logic where it loads content before adding the layer completely.

Comment: I thought I had to add the layer to the map after I have added all the elements (pushpin) to the layer itself....ok I am going to try that approach thanks.